# K-fold repeated cross validation for classification accuracy in Caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I am new to cross-validation and I have a data-set called LDA.scores for 12 measured call-type parameters. I am trying to run a k-fold repeated cross validation with 10 folds and associated naive Bayes method. The grouping factor is Family, since I am trying to assimilate if call-type parameters between between both families are different. I am trying to run this code

```
 library(caret)
 train_control<-trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
 model<-train(Family~., data=LDA.scores, trControl=train_control,method="nb")
 predictions <- predict(model, LDA.scores[,2:13])
 confusionMatrix(predictions,LDA.scores$Family)
```

I keep on getting these error messages:

```
 Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : 
 wrong model type for regression
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.  How can I run this code to produce a naive Bayes matrix.  Any advice would be deeply appreciated. I have tried everything possible with my novel capabilities. Words cannot describe my gratitude if anyone has a solution.  Here is a portion of my dataframe:

```
      Family SBI.max.Part.1 SBI.max.Part.2 SBI.min.Part.1 SBI.min.Part.2
1         G8    -0.48055680   -0.086292700   -0.157157188   -0.438809944
2         G8     0.12600625   -0.074481895    0.057316151   -0.539013927
3         G8     0.06823834   -0.056765686    0.064711783   -0.539013927
4         G8     0.67480139   -0.050860283    0.153459372   -0.539013927
5         G8     0.64591744   -0.050860283    0.072107416   -0.472211271
6         G8     0.21265812   -0.068576492    0.057316151   -0.071395338
7         G8    -0.01841352   -0.068576492   -0.053618335   -0.071395338
8         G8     0.12600625    0.055436970    0.012942357    0.296019267
9         G8    -0.22060120    0.114491000   -0.038827070    0.563229889
10        G8     0.27042603   -0.021333268    0.049920519   -0.037994010
11        G8     0.03935439   -0.044954880    0.012942357    0.195815284
12        G8    -0.45167284    0.008193747   -0.075805232   -0.171599321
13        G8    -0.04729748   -0.056765686    0.035129254   -0.305204632
14        G8    -0.10506539    0.008193747   -0.046222702    0.062209973
15        G8     0.09712230    0.037720761    0.109085578   -0.104796666
16        G8    -0.07618143    0.014099150   -0.038827070    0.095611301
17        G8     0.29930998    0.108585597    0.057316151    0.028808645
18        G8     0.01047043   -0.074481895    0.020337989   -0.071395338
19        G8    -0.24948516    0.002288344    0.035129254    0.329420595
20        G8    -0.04729748    0.049531567    0.057316151    0.296019267
21        G8    -0.01841352    0.043626164    0.005546724   -0.171599321
22        G8    -0.19171725    0.049531567   -0.016640173   -0.071395338
23        G8    -0.48055680    0.020004552   -0.142365923    0.596631217
24        G8     0.01047043    0.008193747    0.220020063    0.062209973
25        G8    -0.42278889    0.025909955   -0.149761556    0.028808645
26        G8    -0.45167284    0.031815358   -0.134970291   -0.138197994
27        G8    -0.30725307    0.049531567    0.042524886    0.095611301
28        G8     0.24154207   -0.039049477    0.072107416   -0.104796666
29        G8     1.45466817   -0.003617059    0.064711783    0.296019267
30        G8    -0.01841352    0.002288344    0.020337989    0.028808645
31        G8     0.38596185    0.084963985    0.049920519   -0.037994010
32        G8     0.15489021   -0.080387298    0.020337989   -0.338605960
33        G8    -0.04729748    0.067247776    0.138668107    0.129012629
34        V4     0.27042603    0.031815358    0.049920519    0.195815284
35        V4    -0.07618143    0.037720761    0.020337989   -0.037994010
36        V4    -0.10506539    0.025909955   -0.083200864    0.396223251
37        V4    -0.01841352    0.126301805   -0.024035805    0.362821923
38        V4     0.01047043    0.031815358   -0.016640173   -0.138197994
39        V4     0.06823834    0.037720761   -0.038827070    0.262617940
40        V4    -0.16283329   -0.050860283   -0.038827070   -0.405408616
41        V4    -0.01841352   -0.039049477    0.005546724   -0.205000649
42        V4    -0.39390493   -0.003617059   -0.090596497    0.129012629
43        V4    -0.04729748    0.008193747   -0.009244540    0.195815284
44        V4     0.01047043   -0.039049477   -0.016640173   -0.205000649
45        V4     0.01047043   -0.003617059   -0.075805232   -0.004592683
46        V4     0.06823834    0.008193747   -0.090596497   -0.205000649
47        V4    -0.04729748    0.014099150    0.012942357   -0.071395338
48        V4    -0.22060120   -0.015427865   -0.075805232   -0.171599321
49        V4    -0.16283329    0.020004552   -0.061013967   -0.104796666
50        V4    -0.07618143    0.031815358   -0.038827070   -0.138197994
51        V4    -0.22060120    0.020004552   -0.112783394   -0.104796666
52        V4    -0.19171725   -0.033144074   -0.068409599   -0.071395338
53        V4    -0.16283329   -0.039049477   -0.090596497   -0.104796666
54        V4    -0.22060120   -0.009522462   -0.053618335   -0.037994010
55        V4    -0.13394934   -0.003617059   -0.075805232   -0.004592683
56        V4    -0.27836911   -0.044954880   -0.090596497   -0.238401977
57        V4    -0.04729748   -0.050860283    0.064711783    0.028808645
58        V4     0.01047043   -0.044954880    0.012942357   -0.305204632
59        V4     0.12600625   -0.068576492    0.042524886   -0.305204632
60        V4     0.06823834   -0.033144074   -0.061013967   -0.271803305
61        V4     0.06823834   -0.027238671   -0.061013967   -0.037994010
62        V4     0.32819394   -0.068576492    0.064711783   -0.372007288
63        V4     0.32819394    0.014099150    0.175646269    0.095611301
64        V4    -0.27836911    0.002288344   -0.068409599    0.195815284
65        V4     0.18377416    0.025909955    0.027733621    0.162413956
66        V4     0.55926557   -0.009522462    0.042524886    0.229216612
67        V4    -0.19171725   -0.009522462   -0.038827070    0.229216612
68        V4    -0.19171725    0.025909955   -0.009244540    0.396223251
69        V4     0.01047043    0.155828820    0.027733621    0.630032545
70        V4    -0.19171725    0.002288344   -0.031431438    0.463025906
71        V4    -0.01841352   -0.044954880   -0.046222702    0.496427234
72        V4    -0.07618143   -0.015427865   -0.031431438    0.062209973
73        V4    -0.13394934    0.008193747   -0.068409599   -0.071395338
74        V4    -0.39390493    0.037720761   -0.120179026    0.229216612
75        V4    -0.04729748    0.008193747    0.035129254   -0.071395338
76        V4    -0.27836911   -0.015427865   -0.061013967   -0.071395338
77        V4     0.70368535   -0.056765686    0.397515240   -0.205000649
78        V4     0.29930998    0.079058582    0.138668107    0.229216612
79        V4    -0.13394934   -0.056765686    0.020337989   -0.305204632
80        V4     0.21265812    0.025909955    0.035129254    0.396223251

   'data.frame':    80 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Family           : Factor w/ 2 levels "G8","V4": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 .                  
     $ SBI.max.Part.1   : num  -0.4806 0.126 0.0682 0.6748 0.6459 ...
 $ SBI.max.Part.2   : num  -0.0863 -0.0745 -0.0568 -0.0509 -0.0509 ...
     $ SBI.min.Part.1   : num  -0.1572 0.0573 0.0647 0.1535 0.0721 ...
 $ SBI.min.Part.2   : num  -0.439 -0.539 -0.539 -0.539 -0.472 ...
```

Comment: For some reason caret seems to believe that Family is a continuous variable, but it looks categorical (it only contains values "G8" and "V4",...), so it should work. I copy&pasted your code and used an artificial data set - it works - so I think something's wrong with your LDA.scores dataset. Can you post the data set & the code you use to load it?

Comment: Please register & merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Alice, as gung says, please register and merge your accounts using the links he provided. Among other benefits, you'll then be able to edit your own posts without review and you'll be able to comment anywhere in your own questions.

Answer (score 2):

You should check out http://topepo.github.io/caret/Bayesian_Model.html

Right now you have a target variable that is continuous and you are trying to apply a classification algorithm to it. Instead, you should use something like `brnn` or `bartMachine`

Comment: The variable "Family" is categorical (it only contains values "G8" and "V4").. I think the code should work with that. Something else seems to be wrong..

Comment: Can you run str(LDA.scores) so we can get a breakout of what the data looks like from that perspective? I tried your exact code with the iris data set and it worked fine.

Comment: Alice attempted to edit your post to add "Hi Jason, I placed the structure of my data underneath the data.frame.  Sorry I have been away".